# How to open blister packs without cutting yourself?

Tags: home, substitute-tool, packaging

There are some very annoying blister packs (such as memory cards, pendrives, superglue, etc.) where whole pack is laminated with hard material and there is no way to open it without the scissors or breaking the thing which you bought.

But what if you don't have scissors around and using knife is very risky and painful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a can opener around, try to open the blister packs with it.

[image: Use a can opener to open blister packs and avoid cutting yourself.]